# Why do I get the error "Xml data type is not supported in distributed queries" when querying a linked server for non-xml data?

Tags: sql-server, xml, linked-server

I have two SQL Servers (running SQL Server 2008) named `DATA01` and `DATA02`. `DATA02` has a linked server definition `LINK`, that points at `DATA01`, with suitable user mapping set up. On `DATA01` there is a database `MyDatabase` containing these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE T_A (
    Id int
)

CREATE TABLE T_B (
    Id int,
    Stuff xml
)
```

When I run this command from `DATA02`, I get data returned as expected:

```
SELECT Id FROM LINK.MyDatabase.dbo.T_A;
```

However, when I run this command from `DATA02`, I get an error:

```
SELECT Id, Stuff FROM LINK.MyDatabase.dbo.T_B;
```

The error is

> Xml data type is not supported in distributed queries. Remote object 'DATA02.MyDatabase.dbo.T_B' has xml column(s).

And strangely, this command:

```
SELECT Id FROM LINK.MyDatabase.dbo.T_B;
```

also gives the same error, **even though I'm not `SELECT`ing the xml column!** What's going on?

Comment: An undesired "feature" - even if the XML column(s) are excluded, distributed queries generate the specified error with just one bad apple (a XML column).

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This is a deficiency within SQL Server. The mere **existence** of an xml column on the table prevents it from participating in distributed queries (eg being queried through a linked server connection). This [is mentioned in this 'retired' documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175129(v=sql.105)). There doesn't appear to be any mention of this in the current version's documentation.

There used to be relevant bug reports on Microsoft Connect, but that's now been 'retired' in favour of the Azure feedback forums. [This feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32890999-tables-with-xml-columns-cannot-be-queried-using-di) is Closed with an instruction to "Please submit feedback directly from the product documentation", which would be fine if the product documentation actually mentioned this. [This other feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32894476-msft-maddog-can-t-do-a-distributed-query-into-a) includes commentary migrated from Connect, and has the status 'Unplanned'.

One of the Connect bug reports that used to exist gave two workarounds:

1. > Create [a] view without the XML column(s) on remote server and query that.

   In your example, this would involve adding a view to `MyDatabase`
   that looks like this:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW V_T_B AS SELECT Id FROM T_B;
   ```

   You could then query this view through the link to get the `Id`
   data. Note that something like

   ```
   SELECT Id FROM ( SELECT Id FROM T_B ) T_B;
   ```

   *doesn't* work.
2. > Use a pass-through query in the form

   > ```
   > SELECT * from OPENQUERY (... )
   > ```

   This method has the advantage of not requiring any change to the
   source database; the downside is that it is no longer possible to
   use standard four-part naming for both local and linked data. The
   query would look like

   ```
    SELECT Id FROM OPENQUERY(DATA02, 'SELECT Id FROM T_B') T_B;
   ```

   Note that if you actually *do* want the xml data, this method (along
   with casting to and from a non-xml datatype) will be *required* :

   ```
    SELECT Id, CAST(Stuff AS XML) Stuff 
    FROM OPENQUERY(DATA02, 'SELECT Id, CAST(Stuff AS nvarchar(max)) Stuff 
                            FROM T_B') T_B;
   ```

Note that the bug was first reported in SQL Server 2005, and remains unfixed in SQL Server 2017. I haven't yet been able to check SQL Server 2019.

Comment: You could also create a stored procedure on DATA02 and call the stored procedure remotely instead of trying to run the query remotely.

Comment: when i create the view on the local DB, from the select id of the remote DB table, i get the same error...SQL SERVER 2008 R2 here

Comment: @RMiranda the view has to be created on the *remote* DB, then from the local DB you should be able to query that view through the link.

Comment: such a simple solution! Thanks

Comment: Just stumbled across it in SQL 2019 (as the connecting server). Maybe its just a misunderstood feature.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

- Create a view on the source side with xml cast to nvarchar(max):

CREATE VIEW vXMLTest
AS
SELECT cast(Stuff as nvarchar(max)) as STUFF FROM T_B

- You can select it on the destination side with cast to xml

*SELECT Cast(Stuff as XML) as Stuff
FROM OPENQUERY(DATA02, 'SELECT Stuff FROM vXMLTest')*

This solution works for me in 2008R2.

Answer (score 10):

I found another way of doing this:

1. Create a `Linked Server` on `DATA01`, `DATA02` or even some third server (could be local).
2. Execute your query using `EXEC [linked_server].[sp_executesql]`.

Why I prefer this method over creating Views or using `OPENQUERY`?

1. This method does not require to have any permissions on the Linked Server (you don't need to create Views).
2. You could pass a parameters to your query using the `sp_executesql` syntax ([find more information about sp_sqlexecute here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)). For `OPENQUERY` you must pass a `STRING` or `TEXT_LEX`, witch means that all the values must be typed right into this function.

Here is the example:

```
DECLARE @UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = ''

DECLARE @SearchForUserParams NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'@UserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER';  
DECLARE @SearchForUserQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'SELECT
    UserID,
    Username,
    Email,
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), UserDataXml) AS UserDataXml
FROM User
WHERE UserID = @UserID'

EXEC [linked_server].[dbo].[sp_executesql] 
    @SearchForUserQuery,
    @SearchForUserParams,
    @UserID = @UserID
```

Comment: Good answer when you need some data from production server and have no posibility to create a view.
But in your example you forgot about database: [linked_server].[DATABASE].dbo.[sp_executesql] ...

Comment: When I try this I get an error: Server 'MySVR\MyDB' is not configured for RPC.

Comment: You need to turn on RPC and RPC out in Properties Pane when configuring Linked Server.