# How to store sp_WhoIsActive result from one server into table on another SQL Server?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

For monitoring and investigation purpose I would like to have the result from `sp_WhoIsActive` (especially the query plan which is xml column) to be stored into table, due to restriction I would have to store the result on another server.

When trying this using link server the error pop:

> Xml data type is not supported in distributed queries. Remote object 'IROWSET' has xml column(s)

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

First you need to get the schema for your parameters as given below:

```
DECLARE @createTableSchema VARCHAR(MAX) 
EXEC sp_WhoIsActive
    @filter = '',
    @filter_type = 'session',
    @not_filter = '',
    @not_filter_type = 'session',
    @show_own_spid = 0,
    @show_system_spids = 0,
    @show_sleeping_spids = 0,
    @get_full_inner_text = 0,
    @get_plans = 1,
    @get_outer_command = 0,
    @get_transaction_info = 1,
    @get_task_info = 1,
    @get_locks = 0,
    @get_avg_time = 0,
    @get_additional_info = 1,
    @find_block_leaders = 0,
    @delta_interval = 0,
    @output_column_list = '[dd%][session_id][sql_text][sql_command][login_name][wait_info][tasks][tran_log%][cpu%][temp%][block%][reads%][writes%][context%][physical%][query_plan][locks][%]',
    @sort_order = '[start_time] ASC',
    @format_output = 1,
    @destination_table = '',
    @return_schema = 1,
    @schema = @createTableSchema OUTPUT,
    @help = 0;
SELECT @createTableSchema
GO
```

Once you get the schema, use that to create table as given below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AuditTableName (
    [dd hh:mm:ss.mss] VARCHAR(8000) NULL
    ,[session_id] SMALLINT NOT NULL
    ,[sql_text] XML NULL
    ,[login_name] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
    ,[wait_info] NVARCHAR(4000) NULL
    ,[tran_log_writes] NVARCHAR(4000) NULL
    ,[CPU] VARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[tempdb_allocations] VARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[tempdb_current] VARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[blocking_session_id] SMALLINT NULL
    ,[reads] VARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[writes] VARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[physical_reads] VARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[query_plan] XML NULL
    ,[used_memory] VARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[status] VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,[tran_start_time] DATETIME NULL
    ,[open_tran_count] VARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[percent_complete] VARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[host_name] NVARCHAR(128) NULL
    ,[database_name] NVARCHAR(128) NULL
    ,[program_name] NVARCHAR(128) NULL
    ,[additional_info] XML NULL
    ,[start_time] DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,[login_time] DATETIME NULL
    ,[request_id] INT NULL
    ,[collection_time] DATETIME NOT NULL
    )
```

Now, mention the Audit table name in the sp_whoisactive call. The data from the sp_whoisactive will be stored in the table.

```
EXEC sp_WhoIsActive
    @filter = '',
    @filter_type = 'session',
    @not_filter = '',
    @not_filter_type = 'session',
    @show_own_spid = 0,
    @show_system_spids = 0,
    @show_sleeping_spids = 0,
    @get_full_inner_text = 0,
    @get_plans = 1,
    @get_outer_command = 0,
    @get_transaction_info = 1,
    @get_task_info = 1,
    @get_locks = 0,
    @get_avg_time = 0,
    @get_additional_info = 1,
    @find_block_leaders = 0,
    @delta_interval = 0,
    @output_column_list = '[dd%][session_id][sql_text][sql_command][login_name][wait_info][tasks][tran_log%][cpu%][temp%][block%][reads%][writes%][context%][physical%][query_plan][locks][%]',
    @sort_order = '[start_time] ASC',
    @format_output = 1,
    @destination_table = 'dbo.AuditTableName',
    @return_schema = 0,
    @schema = NULL,
    @help = 0;
GO
```

You can also refer to detailed article on this by Adam Mechanic himself. [Capturing Output of Whoisactive](http://www.whoisactive.com/docs/25_capturing/)

Answer (score 0):

Brent Ozar has an color excellent example located [here](http://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/). Look at step one to create a destination table.

**However a much more detailed example is located [here](http://whoisactive.com/docs/25_capturing/) by Adam Machanic who I believe wrote this great diagnostic proc and released it to the public.  Thanks Adam!**

> Basically you have to use the parameters @return_schema=1 and @schema
>   as an output variable.  Afterwards you do a replace of ''
>   with a table of your choice.  Then execute it as dynamic SQL.

Comment: I have no problem do what is in the link, in fact I have already done that for a few DB that need monitoring, however the sp_WhoIsActive and result are run and stored on the same DB that need to monitor. For my initial question the output need to be stored in another DB.

Comment: Sorry, missed that point.  Could the table exist for a small amount of time and then you can link server copy the columns you need?  Getting by the XML column could be done using this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442039/why-do-i-get-the-error-xml-data-type-is-not-supported-in-distributed-queries-w).  Again, sorry about missing the first part of it being on a different server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a bunch of SQL servers and want to send all results to one central global production audit server.  This is the method I've used.  This allows you to add additional columns, such as SERVER NAME.  Linked Servers simply does not support the XML data type, it must be a minor modified solution.

You have to convert the XML column into a `VARCHAR(MAX)` and store the Query Plan as a `VARCHAR(MAX)` on the global Table in your other Server.  Do the following steps

1. Create a `<table>` with the `sp_WhoIsActive` schema with the XML column
2. Run `INSERT INTO <table>... EXEC sp_WhoIsActive` to populate that table in one statement
3. Now query the `<table>` while converting XML to `VARCHAR(MAX)`
4. Insert the results of that converted XML to `VARCHAR` into the table in your Linked Server
5. Doing this in a SQL Agent Job also works too.