# SQL - Exporting a table with xml colomun into a text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, transfer

I need to export a table, that contains a XML column (this xml my contain any special characters, so I can not use them as column delimiters) into a text file.

I am using SQL Server 2014. The XML column may contain special characters like `@`, `|`, `,`, `?`, tab, `<cr>` many things that could be used as delimiters.

I want to export the whole table. The XML is not structured internally. The max length of the column is around 6000 characters. The table has around 700k rows. And the destination is the same table in a SQL Server 2012 (lower version than the origin), they are in different networks.

I am trying to export it as a .txt file with `||` as column delimiter. But when I try to import this file into the destination table, it says that the text was truncated and could not be imported.

What's the best way I can do this?

Comment: Which RDBMS (please edit your tags and please state product **and** version)? What is "any special character"? You might poste some example code...

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014. The XML column may contaim special caracters like "@", "|", ",", "?" tabulation, "<cr>" many things that could be used as delimitators.

Comment: Is the XML structured internally? What is the approx. max size of this column?

Comment: Please describe a little more in detail: Do you want to export the whole table or just the XML column? What file format and structure is your expected output?

Comment: One more question :-)  where is the export going to? Is it a path you can reach through SQL Server?

Comment: I want to export the whole table. The XML is not strucketred internally. The max lenght of the column is arround 6000 characters. The table has arround 700k rows. And the destination is the same table in a SQL SERVER 2012 (lower version than the origin), but it is reacheable.

Comment: I am trying to export it as a .txt file with || as column delimitador. But when I try to import this file into the destination table, it says that the text was truncated and could not be imported..

Comment: Are both servers running on the same system?

Comment: yes, both servers are runing on the same system

Comment: If you're trying to import/export between tables on the same server, why not use tools like BCP or SSIS?

Comment: I was tryign with the ssis, but was facing errors like data truncation, and error trying the insert data into the dataflwo buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your answers you gave in your comments give me the idea that you are going the wrong way... The best approach should be `linked servers`:

Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Further information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Try this in your SS2014

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'YourLowerServer', 
    @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;
GO
```

This you need to get access:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
    @rmtsrvname = N'YourLowerServer', 
    @locallogin = NULL , 
    @useself = N'True' ;
GO
```

If this is done you can use the `INSERT INTO` from one server directly to the other server. Try this in your SS2014:

```
INSERT INTO YourLowerServer.YourDatabase.dbo.TableName(col1,col2,...)
SELECT col1,col2,... FROM dbo.TableName
```

If you want to get rid of your linked server after this operation use `sp_dropserver` (read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174310.aspx)

Hope this helps...

Comment: I receive the following error with this method :

"Xml data type is not supported in distributed queries. Remote object 'LOCALHOST.teste.dbo.tbTeste' has xml column(s)."

Comment: Yes, didn't know this. It's a known misbehaviour. I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14442039/5089204. In short: You must create a `VIEW` in your SS2014 where you cast the XML column to `VARCHAR(max)`. Then you create the `linked server` within your `SSLowerServer` and call the 'VIEW' via 'FROM OPENQUERY' . Good luck!

Comment: It worked fine, with the 2 servers inside the same network. But what if I need to transfer this data between 2 servers that are in different network? Would this method still be the most efficient?

Comment: Well, is this something you need regularely, fully automatic, or just now an then? A pragmatical approach was to have a `Stored Procedure` within your SQL Server with the **lowest** version **within** your network. There you have a `CREATE DATABASE`, a `CREATE TABLE`, an `INSERT INTO`, a `BACKUP` and a final `DROP DATABASE`. The resulting BAK-file is most easy to transfer. In your desination you need a `RESTORE`, an `INSERT INTO` and a final `DROP`. Each step is scriptable... Could this help?