# how to insert xml data type across server in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two servers with sql server db say A and B.
I have a table in A with xml data type and a table in B with xml data type.
I want to do insert select the data in A to table in B.

```
insert into [B].[dbo].[T1] select * from [A].[dbo].[T1]
```

But I keep getting error

```
"xml data type is not supported in distributed queries"
```

Comment: It sounds like you are using a linked server. In which case the sample SQL you posted is incorrect. Not to mention only posting half the error. Anyway I googled your error and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442039/why-do-i-get-the-error-xml-data-type-is-not-supported-in-distributed-queries-w

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution.

```
insert into B select xml_field  from openquery([A],'select cast(xml_field as varchar(max)) as xml_field from dbo.t1')
```