# Can not INSERT INTO table which has xml column(s) using Linked server on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, linked-server

[image]

I have problem with **Linked Servers in SQL Server**

I can **SELECT, DELETE and UPDATE record which has XML column(s)** until I do **INSERT record** and then got this error

I am also successful in dong **INSERT record without XML column** but still stuck in doing **INSERT with XML column(s)**

Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442039/why-do-i-get-the-error-xml-data-type-is-not-supported-in-distributed-queries-w

Answer (score 0):

XML datatype is not supported in Linked Servers in SQL Server